# "Error in syntax_table logic for to-the-end intervals" error in emacs

Tags: emacs

I use emacs for most online text editing, for PHP and javascript files especially.  "PHP Abbrev" seems to be the mode for PHP files?

Lately I've been getting this error a lot within emacs, for a specific file:
"Error in syntax_table logic for to-the-end intervals"

The file is upwards of 5000 lines of PHP functions only, with no syntax errors, and runs well.

Yet sometimes (not always) I get that error, which seems to imply some sort of balancing issue.  The worst part is that it prevents me from typing things like { } brackets, and I can't even write the code I need.   Sometimes I need to code within comment brackets for it to allow it, then remove them at the end.

Is there any way to bypass this somehow, or detect if there is actually a balancing issue somewhere?

Comment: Did you already use `toggle-debug-on-error` to get more information about the error? You can also use the menu bar, menu item `Options` and there `Enter Debug on Error`. If you get some reasonable output you should add it to the question.

Comment: I'm using emacs in the straight terminal, so there are no menus.  I tried the toggle-debug-on-error (didn't know about this before), and I get:    forward-comment(-1)
  c-backward-sws()
  c-guess-basic-syntax()
  c-indent-line()
  indent-according-to-mode()
  c-electric-paren(nil)
  call-interactively(c-electric-paren)

Comment: Is there a way to jump to the found error?  Those are all just a text list in emacs.

Comment: This reflects a bug in the C code.  Please report it with `M-x report-emacs-bug` with as much detail as possible to reproduce the problem.  Of course, first try to reproduce it with the latest Emacs you can find, in case the bug has been fixed already.

Comment: There is something very similar in http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.cc-mode.general/1769. Could you check whether your emacs is affected. My emacs 24.3.1 does not show the error with the reproduction hints given there. If your version shows the error maybe you should just update?

Comment: FYI-- the emacs on my ISP server is "GNU Emacs 21.4.1", quite old, though still quite competent.  This is circa 2002 apparently.